# mobx-state-tree: How to clone a model that includes references?

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm trying to clone a model that references another model, but I get: `Error: [mobx-state-tree] Failed to resolve reference 'H1qH2j20z' to type 'AnonymousModel' (from node: /usualCustomer)...` in the clone. The original resolves okay.

Here are my models:

```
const Job = types.model({
    id: types.optional(types.identifier(types.string), shortid.generate()),
    jobNumber: types.optional(types.string, ''),
    description: '',
    usualCustomer: types.maybe(types.reference(Customer)),
  })

const Customer = types.model({
    id: types.optional(types.identifier(types.string), shortid.generate()),
    name: types.optional(types.string, 'New customer'),
  })
```

This function shows the problem:

```
editJob = job => {
    console.log('Original', job)
    var newClone = clone(job)
    console.log('Clone', newClone)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try also to change the identifier of the node you want to clone ?

i'm not sure if it will work. but when you clone the job node, i think the new created job newJob act as a reference to the cloned job, give it a try anyway :

```
let jobFromSnap = getSnapshot(job);  
let newJob = Job.create({...jobFromSnap, id : "NEW_ID_HERE" }) ;
```